# how count and sum records in three tables using mysql phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I m new to this community and also new to MySQL.

Need to `COUNT` the clients and `SUM` the commission for each referrer respectively using MySQL query.

referrer table

| id | referrer_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | referre1 |
| 2 | referre2 |
| 3 | referre3 |
| 4 | referre4 |

client table

| id | referrer_id | client_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | client1 |
| 2 | 1 | client2 |
| 3 | 2 | client3 |
| 4 | 3 | client4 |
| 5 | 4 | client5 |

commission table

| id | client_id | commission |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 32 |
| 3 | 3 | 24 |
| 4 | 4 | 15 |

I want to achieve below output using above 3 tables.

| referrer_id | referrer_name | total_client | total_commission |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | referre1 | 2 | 52 |
| 2 | referre2 | 1 | 24 |
| 3 | referre3 | 1 | 15 |
| 4 | referre4 | 1 | 0 |

I have tried the following query

```
 SELECT referrer.referrer_name as name,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM client WHERE client.referrer_id=referrer.id) as total_client,
(SELECT SUM(commission) FROM commission WHERE commission.client_id=client.id) as total_commission FROM referrer LEFT JOIN client ON client.referrer_id=referrer.id GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Please learn and do some research before asking question, we are not here to solve your assignment for you, if you get stuck in the way of doing it we can help you but simply asking to solve your homework does not help you in anyway.

Comment: The reason is just above your comment.

Comment: Is this assignment , this is the problem and you do not have solution. so making usefulness reasons here.

Comment: Did you try to solve it in anyway? Did you get any errors doing that?

Comment: Of course I try  from 12 hours and I use php codeigniter 3. it not display ,sometime it count same clients for every referrer and some time only zero.

Comment: If you tried so hard, you could have shown us what query you have written and we would help you correct that. Also, do upvote the answer that got you right.

Comment: I have updated the question and query which I tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read [Mysql join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) and [Aggregate Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

```
SELECT t2.referrer_id,
       t1.referrer_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT t2.id) AS total_client,
       SUM(t3.commission)                 AS total_commission
FROM referrer t1
         JOIN client t2 ON t1.id = t2.referrer_id
         JOIN commission t3 ON t2.id = t3.client_id
GROUP BY t1.referrer_id
```

Comment: Thanks @Soheil Rahsaz

Comment: Can we use where clause or left join in this query.?

Comment: @onlinegsali of course, put `WHERE` before group by. `LEFT JOIN` is also possible. Be careful that `sum()` returns null if there is nothing to sum